# Cannot add event listener for "EVENT_EDITMODE_CREATION_END" in MarkupsCore extension

Tags: autodesk-forge

I tried to add event listener for event "EVENT_EDITMODE_CREATION_END" in MarkupsCore extension:

```
markupsExtension.addEventListener('EVENT_EDITMODE_CREATION_END', () => {console.log('Test');});
```

But the event hander has never been executed when adding/editing markups in the viewer.
I know "EVENT_EDITMODE_CREATION_END" is not listed in the forge official documentation
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/markupscore/

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `EVENT_EDITMODE_CREATION_END` event is dispatched on the specific "edit mode" object, not on the markups extension object. In order to get notified of the event, you would have to subscribe to the event on the `markupsExt.editMode` object whenever the mode changes, for example, like so:

```js
markupsExt.editMode.addEventListener('EVENT_EDITMODE_CREATION_END', function (ev) { console.log('Markup creation ended!'); });
```