# How to handle Markups Core events to leave Edit mode appropriately?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am creating a custom extension class which will load the MarkupsCore extension to the viewer. The custom extension class will also create a button on the toolbar when the toolbar is created.

On Load(), I load the Markups extension to the viewer, set its instance as a property of the custome xtension class and then add event listener to the EVENT_EDITMODE_CREATION_END which should trigger once the user finished drawing a markup on the viewer. Once the event is triggered, I would like to leave the edit mode.

On Button click, I start the Edit Mode using the enterEditMode().

The code works fine up until entering the edit mode. However, once the user finished drawing the markup, the event was not triggered and as a result, the leaveEditMode() is not called and the viewer is stuck in the edit mode. How should I properly handle this event and call the leaveEditMode after the user has finished drawing the markup? (This is just for testing purposes, later on I will implement data generation and saving of the markups).

Here's my code snippet:

```
import { BaseExtension } from './BaseExtension.js';

class MarkupExtension extends BaseExtension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
        this._button = null;
    }

    load() {
        super.load();

        // Load the MarkupsCore extension to the viewer
        this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore')
            .then((markupExt) => {
                this._markupCoreExt = markupExt;

                // Adds Listeners to MarkupsCore Events
                this._markupCoreExt.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EVENT_EDITMODE_CREATION_END, (ev) => {
                    console.log(ev.markup);
                    this._markupCoreExt.leaveEditMode();
                    this._markupCoreExt.hide();
                });
            });

        console.log('MarkupExtension loaded.');
        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        super.unload();

        // Removes button and panel on unload
        if (this._button) {
            this.removeToolbarButton(this._button);
            this._button = null;
        }

        console.log('MarkupExtension unloaded.');
        return true;
    }

    onToolbarCreated() { // Called by viewer when the toolbar is ready, invoked by TOOLBAR_CREATED_EVENT
        console.log('Start of Toolbar Creation Event');
        // Sets the Button for Markup Creation
        let group = this.viewer.toolbar.getControl('dashboard-toolbar-group');
        this._button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('markup-edit-mode-button');
        this._button.setToolTip('Markup Mode');
        this._button.onClick = () => {
            this._markupCoreExt.allowNavigation(true);
            this._markupCoreExt.enterEditMode();
            let cloudMode = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EditModeCloud(this._markupCoreExt);
            this._markupCoreExt.changeEditMode(cloudMode);
        };
        group.addControl(this._button);
        console.log('Button Added');
    }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('MarkupExtension', MarkupExtension);
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, did you get a chance to use my code and let us know if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Fired whenever the drawing tool changes. For example, when the Arrow drawing tool changes into the Rectangle drawing tool.
markupext.addEventListener('EVENT_EDITMODE_CHANGED', function (ev) {
    const editTool = ev.target;
    if (editTool) {
        //Fired when a markup has been created. For example, as soon as the user stops dragging and releases the mouse button to finish drawing an arrow on the screen
        editTool.addEventListener('EVENT_EDITMODE_CREATION_END', function (ev) {
            saveMarkups(). // or do something else
        });
        // Fired when a markup is no longer selected.
        editTool.addEventListener('EVENT_MARKUP_DESELECT', function (ev) {
            saveMarkups() // or do something else
        });
    }
});

// The selected markup is no longer being modified
markupext.editFrame.addEventListener('EVENT_EDITFRAME_EDITION_END', function (ev) {
    saveMarkups() // or do something else
});
```

Ref: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs/tree/markups-persist

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer, I have actually found the answer by assigning the event listener to the markupExt.editModeas mentioned by Peter in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68928596/cannot-add-event-listener-for-event-editmode-creation-end-in-markupscore-exten). I will mark my question as a duplicate.